# Search for registry change during wix installation

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I have a radio button to choose options, which select type installation. If they choose option 1 the installer can not continue is mozilla firefox is not installed...

The problem is: imagine that user get message that he needs mozilla firefox... so he decide to install it, but do not close my installation... so after what he installs firefox click on next button in my installation and again get message that he needs to install firefox...

Next button check and show message:

```
<Publish Dialog="AdditionalInfo" Control="Next" Event="SpawnDialog" Value="MozillaCheck" Order="5">INSTALLATION_TYPE = "PORTAL" AND NOT FIREFOXVERSION</Publish>
```

firefox check:

```
<Property Id="FIREFOXVERSION">
        <RegistrySearch Id='FirefoxVersion_registrySearch' Type='raw'
            Root='HKLM' Key='SOFTWARE\Mozilla\Mozilla Firefox' Name='CurrentVersion' Win64='no'/>
    </Property>
```

I was looking for some custom action which I can trigger at DoAction event, but it seems that there is no registrySearch custom action...

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure if it is possible by default, so I decided to create custom action in C#, where I can detect it easily by looking into registry